# How to grunt serve a yeoman app in Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I've set up an angular site using Yeoman, put it on git, and have cloned the repository in a newly set up Cloud9 IDE workspace.  Everything builds and I can run the "grunt serve" command in the CLI.  When I try to go to `http://localhost:9000` (the default url specified in the grunt file), the page doesn't load.

What do I need to do to get this working in Cloud9 IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a resolved question but for people running into this now, I'll update it a bit.

If you want to run a server on your Cloud9 hosted workspace, you need to bind it to `0.0.0.0:8080`, so IP=`0.0.0.0` and PORT=`8080` not `localhost:9000`.

You can update your gruntfile to make it work.